# Problemas al insertar booleanos en matriz python

Tags: python, numpy, booleano

Lo mas sencillo para explicar mi problema, es explicarlo mediante un ejemplo.

Aquí tenemos un ejercicio en código MATLAB, el cual quiero aprender a usar en python.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al "traducir" el ejercicio a python (sólo interesa la parte de a), obtengo lo siguiente

```
a = np.array([[0.8147, 0.9134, 0.2785], [ 0.9058, 0.6324, 0.5469], [0.1270, 0.0865, 0.9575]])
bool_1 = np.array([False, True, True])
bool_2 = np.array([True, False, True])
print(a[bool_1,bool_2])
```

Este es el resultado:

```
[0.9058 0.9575]
```

Obviamente esto es erróneo, imagino que es la forma de analizar los booleanos en python.
¿De qué forma podría resolver este ejercicio de una forma similar a la resuelta en MATLAB?
He encontrado una forma, pero me parece muy tosco, y tiene que existir una opción más sencilla.

```
mat_bool = np.array([ [False, False, False], 
                     [True, False, True], 
                     [True, False, True]
                     ])
print(a[mat_bool].reshape(2,2))
```

Agradezco vuestra ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma de hacer esa selección en numpy es la siguiente

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(
    [
        [0.8147, 0.9134, 0.2785],
        [0.9058, 0.6324, 0.5469],
        [0.1270, 0.0865, 0.9575],
    ]
)

bool_1 = np.array([False, True, True])
bool_2 = np.array([True, False, True])

a[bool_1][:,bool_2]
```

El resultado es:

```
array([
    [0.9058, 0.5469],
    [0.127 , 0.9575],
])
```

Puedes leer sobre los modos de indexado en [la documentación (en inglés)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#basic-indexing).

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el por qué se usa esa expresión (vi la documentación pero pone que los brakets separados son == a ponerlo todo junto, aunque no se como funcionará en booleanos). Igual me sirve de mucha ayuda pues es lo que buscaba. Muchas gracias